# How to migrate geoserver?

Tags: geoserver

I have a geoserver installed on a server and I want to move the geoserver to another server. What is the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically all the configuration lives in the geoserver data directory, so that is essentially all you need to migrate.

http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/datadirectory/index.html

You can then install geoserver on the new server however you want and point it at the data directory you migrated from the old server. Also if you have any data that is "external" (ie not inside of your data directory) you will need to migrate that to the new server as well.

Answer (score 3):

1. copy folder "data" in geoserver to on another computer and replace it to .war and geoserver folder
2. dump database old to new computer
3. restart tomcat `/etc/init.d/tomcat7 restart`
4. change owner "data" on geoserver to  tomcat user

   `-cd to /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geoserver`

   `sudo chown -R tomcat7 data`

   `sudo chown -R :tomcat7 data`
5. reload store on geoserver