# Transfer OpenLayers map from one pc to another

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, error, copy

I have a following question, I created a web application - I used geoserver to create an openlayers map. As a sever I was using apache tomcat. If i want to run this server on different machine, what files/settingd I would have to transfer!? I just installed everything on different machine, for map however I can see zoom buttons and stuff like that- but there is no map... Have anyone done it before? Many thanks!

Comment: are you moving geoserver also to new machine ?

Comment: yes obviosly, all the application running in apache tomcat

Comment: check out [How to migrate geoserver?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23654/how-to-migrate-geoserver) and [Migrating a Data Directory between different versions](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/datadirectory/migrating.html)